# Copied backup to C drive after updating Windows, but I cannot find or access my files

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-8.1, windows-backup

I just upgraded from Windows XP to Windows 8.1. Before doing so I made a backup of all my files and moved them to an external drive. After I installed Windows 8.1, I copied all my files back to a folder in my C drive. Now the C drive appears to have all my files, judging by the occupied space (180 gigas aprox), but when I enter the folder where I put them, my files are nowhere to be found. I've tried searching and browsing through the hidden files, but nothing.

My guess at this point is that something went very wrong with the transfer, and that I'll just need to format the computer and try again, but before doing so I thought on asking. Thanks!

Comment: try running a `CHKDSK /F`.

Comment: How did you copy the files back? If this was a done through some old backup program which is not Windows 8 aware, it may have moved them to  the virtual store. If so, you can find them by browsing to %LocalAppData%\VirtualStore

Comment: The files may be there but not visible to you because of a rights issue. Make sure you are logged  in as an administrator equivalent.